# Bash - start multiple services if any is running CentOS 6.8

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to check if one, (or all) services are running, if yes, stop it

```
#!/bin/bash


# Define an array of processes to be checked.
# If properly quoted, these may contain spaces

check_process=( "nagios" "httpd" )

for p in "${check_process[@]}"; do
    if pgrep "$p" > /dev/null; then
        echo "Process \`$p' is running, stopping it"
        service $p stop
    else
        echo "Process \`$p' is not running"
    fi
done
```

For httpd service all works fine, script detects correctly `httpd` service state.
I have issues detecting `nagios` service state.
But although `nagios` service is not running, script shows it's running

```
Process `nagios' is running, stopping it
Stopping nagios:No lock file found in /usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.lock
Process `httpd' is not running
```

Is there any more elegant way of detecting if nagios service is running without checking if `nagios.lock` file exists ?

`pgrep nagios` shows no output when service is not tunning.

Comment: Use status: https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Service_command#The_status_command.  Or just call `stop` directly, if it is already stopped, it will just do nothing.

Comment: What Nic3500 said, only that most system these days use `systemd` instead – have a look at the command `systemctl`.

Comment: i'm using CentOS 6, no systemctl there

Comment: why not just run `service "$p" stop` unconditionally?

Comment: if nothing else helps, i'll do it that way

Answer (score 0):

I gave up, this works fine for me:

although `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l` shows 0 for nagios, script reports that nagios service is running

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile=/tmp/stop_nagios.txt

exec >> $logfile

exec 2>&1


service=httpd

if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
   echo "$service is running, stopping it"
   date
   sudo service $service stop


else
   echo "$service is not running"

fi

 # check nagios service    

FILE=/usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.lock
if test -f "$FILE"; then
    echo "nagios service is running, stopping it"
    date
    sudo service nagios stop
else
    echo "nagios is not running..."


fi
```